# How to Import Product Meta Title for Multi Store Website in magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, import-products

I have multi store website in Magento 2. I want to import different different Meta Title as per store by CSV file.
i am using bellow format but its not working for me.
SkU     store_view_code    meta_title

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. It will help others too.

Comment: it did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Use following fields in CSV and import again.

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,meta_title
```

Comment: i am using this type of csv format but its not working for me. can you tell me about store_view_code. in which table saving this

Comment: can you send me csv format i have two store one default and second is usa

Comment: You can check store code from Stores > All Stores

Comment: You can create two different CSVs. One for default store view by keeping empty in store_view_code field and another for 2nd store view by writing store code in store_view_code field. Then import one by one CSV.

Comment: i tried with individual file but it did not work for me.

Comment: what is the error ?